# Why we cast android Activity to Interface in Fragment onAttach()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

As documentation we must cast Activity to Interface in onAttach() to communicate between Fragment-to-Fragment.

```
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
```

After this we can implement that interface in Activity class and use it's methods.
But, i want to know that, as that interface is implemented by Activity class.

Then, why don't we instantiate it in Fragment onAttach() like below:

```
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback = new ActivityClass();// After this all methods are also available in fragment class.
```

Using this way we can also pass the data by using Interface methods. But, why don't we use this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a new instance of an Android component (`Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, Provider`) using the `new` keyword. Only the Android framework can create these components, because they need to have their `Context` set up by the Android framework during construction. Although the compiler will let you do this, and your code will run, at some point you will get crashes because the methods in these components always assume that they have a valid `Context`.

Comment: Thanks David, But, i am confused a bit. If i have my data(returned from Fragment class through instantiated interface function) in Activity class, then why it through NullPointerException while setting it to text view. Even i am using it in the activity class. It should not matter from where i got this data.

Comment: You have 2 instances of your `Activity`. One that Android created properly and one that you created using `new`. The one that you created isn't set up properly. The `Context` hasn't been set up and `onCreate()` hasn't been called. That instance has no `TextView`s, because `setContentView()` hasn't yet been called.

Comment: Oh, got it now. My confusion is clear now. I have got a down vote for a worth question. lol Thanks David.